# how to insert the whole edittext in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and I thought that everything should be working fine but just noticed that if I have a lengthy review, it tends to get cut-off as shown in the image below.. Not sure why this is happening? This is my xml file

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Add a Review here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@id/clinic_name"
    android:id="@+id/review"/>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rePZa.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have    `android:maxLength="200"`, which means no matter what you do, the text in the edit text will not exceed 200 chars

Comment: that's true but I only wrote a sentence though, which should be less than 200 characters...

Comment: I think you are right but it seems to be less than 200 characters though.... that is strange

Comment: actually, it was working before but firebase displayed a ... and I have to click on it to expand it... apologies